# linking verbal clauses with conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions, commas, adverbial-phrases, reduced-relative-clauses, linking-verbs

Why is the case that the below sentence has three verbs that weren't linked with any conjunction? Also, why use the comma prior to the last clause.

I don't know exactly why this sentence is structured as it is. I assume there were reduced parts or some parts of the clauses omitted.

A pupil of Freud (named) Wilhelm Reich (proposed) a theory (construed) out of the root of Freud's libido (,) of psychic energy he came to term orgone energy.

Comment: What do **you** think?

Comment: I don't know exactly why this sentence is structured as it is. I assume there were reduced parts or some parts of the clauses omitted.

Comment: Where did you find that sentence? Please give a reference as it does not look as though it was written by an English speaker.

Comment: https://handwiki.org/wiki/Philosophy:Energy_(psychological)

Comment: Is it an original sentence, or has someone "tweaked" it a little?

Comment: https://handwiki.org/wiki/Philosophy:Energy_(psychological)#:~:text=A%20pupil%20of%20Freud%20named%20Wilhelm%20Reich%20proponed%20a%20theory%20construed%20out%20of%20the%20root%20of%20Freud%27s%20libido%2C%20of%20psychic%20energy%20he%20came%20to%20term%20orgone%20energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[A pupil of Freud **named** Wilhelm Reich] **proposed** [a theory*
> ***construed** *out of the root of Freud's libido, of psychic energy he* *came* to term orgone energy*.

Not all subordinate clauses require a conjunction.

The first verb, "named", introduces the past participial clause *named Wilhelm Reich*, which is directly modifying *pupil of Freud* in the noun phrase subject *a pupil of Freud named Wilhelm Reich*.

The second verb, "proposed", is the main, or matrix verb, of the sentence so it does not require a conjunction.

The third verb, "construed", is like the first: it introduces the past participial clause *construed out of the root of Freud's libido, of psychic energy he came to term orgone energy*, which is directly modifying "theory" in the noun phase *a theory construed out of the root of Freud's libido, of psychic energy he came to term orgone energy*.

There is another verb/clause within the last one, but you didn't ask about it.

The comma after "libido" *appears* to indicate that the two expressions *of the root of Freud's libido* and *of psychic energy he came to term orgone energy* relate jointly to the preposition "out".

Comment: that was extraordinarily clear. one last question, can I assume that there were omitted conjunction "that" prior to "he came to term orgone energy." ?                                                                                                        is the last noun phrase "a theory construed out of the root of Freud's libido, of psychic energy [he came to term orgone energy] can be reduced to " a theory (that) he came to term orgone energy"?

Comment: There is another verb/clause within the last one, but you didn't ask about it.
can you please explain to me where the conjunction of the verb/clause within the last one?

Comment: @MBR Yes: "a theory [(that) he came to term orgone energy]", where the element in square brackets is a relative clause modifying "theory", in which the conjunction "that" is optional.

Comment: I know I said it was the last question but I assume it won't be a problem. Why there is a comma before "of psychic" instead of "and". if a comma was used, does it need another comma after "psychic" and prior to "he" as a "Nonrestrictive appositives."

Comment: @MBR Yes: the comma could be replaced by "and". I would advise against changing the original sentence, since the changes may affect the grammar and/or the meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much. Browsing online, I came across the sentence. containing much challenging grammar rules, the sentence, for me, was a great learning gateway. Analysing sentences help me to learn efficientlly.  thanks